# Почему переменная равна null?

Tags: typescript, angular, chrome-extension

Есть метод, который отправляет данные в расширение хрома и получает ответ:

```
myMethod(): void {
    const editorExtensionId = 'someId';
    const message = {
      msg: 'someMsg',
      arr: 'someArr',
    };
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, message, res => {
      if (res === 0) {
        alert('...');
        return 0;
      }
      if (res.error !== 0) {
        if (res.error === -1) {
          alert('...');
        }
        return 0;
      }

      if (res.certsCount == null || res.certsCount === 0) {
        alert('...');
        return 0;
      }
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    });
  }
```

Вызывая console.log(res) в консоли отображается объект, который мне нужен. В компоненте в переменную записываю результат вызова метода:

```
      getCertificates(): void {
    this.cert$ = this.authService.myMethod();
}
```

Почему переменная cert$ равна null? И как это исправить? Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Во первых

Ты пишешь

> `myMethod(): void`

***void*** предпологает что ф-я ничего не возвращает.

а затем

> `this.cert$ = this.authService.myMethod();`

если ты используешь IDE ты должен был получить тут ошибку и уже в этот момент "заподозрить неладное".

*в качестве IDE рекомендую VSCode*

### Почему?

> Почему переменная равна null?

#### в типах(TypeScript)

потому что `myMethod(): void`

#### в JavaScript

Потому что `myMethod` ничего не возвращает, в отличии от `callBack` ф-ии, внутри которой и выполняется `console.log(res);`

```
class Q {
    myMethod(): void {
        const editorExtensionId = 'someId';
        const message = {
            msg: 'someMsg',
            arr: 'someArr',
        };
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, message, callBack);
        function callBack(res) {
            if (res === 0) {
                alert('...');
                return 0;
            }
            if (res.error !== 0) {
                if (res.error === -1) {
                    alert('...');
                }
                return 0;
            }

            if (res.certsCount == null || res.certsCount === 0) {
                alert('...');
                return 0;
            }
            console.log(res);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

### как?

- Promise - https://learn.javascript.ru/promise
- async/await - https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

**Б**ез гарантий. как-то так:

```
type $res = any
class Q {
    async myMethod(): Promise<$res> {
        const editorExtensionId = 'someId';
        const message = {
            msg: 'someMsg',
            arr: 'someArr',
        };
        const promise: Promise<$res> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, message, resolve);
        })

        const res: $res = await promise;

        if (res === 0) {
            alert('...');
            return 0;
        }
        if (res.error !== 0) {
            if (res.error === -1) {
                alert('...');
            }
            return 0;
        }

        if (res.certsCount == null || res.certsCount === 0) {
            alert('...');
            return 0;
        }
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    }
}
```